# how to get only two gesture work together and one separetly

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am using three gesture named Pan, Pinch and Rotate. I want To use Pinch and Rotate gesture together and Pan separate. I am using `gestureDelegate` method like below :

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true

    }
```

But it runs thrice. I want two Simultaneously.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855645/is-there-a-gesture-recognizer-that-handles-both-pinch-and-pan-together

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented this single method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` than simply remove the `delegate` of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or could not set it.